# How to set StatusDescription from Kestrel server?

Tags: c#, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

How to set HTTP status descrption from Kestrel Server? I want to return 
`HTTP/1.1 400 ArgumentException` instead of `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` but can't find `StatusDescription` property in `DefaultHttpResponse`, I can only change `StatusCode` with numeric code.

Here is the sample App:

https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/tree/dev/samples/SampleApp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access the HTTP context features to override the reason phrase, for example:

```
context.Response
    .HttpContext
    .Features
    .Get<IHttpResponseFeature>()
    .ReasonPhrase = "Stuff here";
```